Excluding specific servers via powershell script
I want to exclude specific computer objects. I have tried something like below. but no luck.
Here is my script :
$ADComputers = @()
$ADGroups = @()
$ComputersNotInAD = @()
$GroupsNotInAD = @()


# Create a single query filter str
$OU = 'OU=Tier1,DC=contoso,DC=local','OU=Servers,DC=contoso,DC=local'
$ADComputersRaw = $OU | ForEach-Object {Get-ADComputer  -Filter {Enabled -eq $True Name -notlike 'server11*' -and Name -notlike 'tstsrv11*'} -SearchBase $PSItem -Properties * | Select-Object name}

# Rebuild the lists to make them text instead of objects
ForEach($ComputerRaw in $ADComputersRaw)
{
    $ADComputers += $ComputerRaw.Name
}


Why don't you just run get-adcomputer once?  Also, you're missing a "-and" in the filter.  "+=" is not ideal.  Why get all the properties and then get rid of them?

You're missing -and in your filter:
{Get-ADComputer  -Filter {Enabled -eq $True -and Name -notlike 'server11*' -and Name -notlike 'tstsrv11*'}
                                            ^^^^

